# Seeking advise on create a maze to solve with BFS in Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, navigation, breadth-first-search

Seeking advise on how structure python to create a maze, solve it with BFS and to have basic navigation within maze with number of moves required to navigate. Use move along the path, Up, Left, Right, Down. Below is some code that I mangled together to think about and figure how to structure python for this BFS algorithm code.

Is anyone open to mentoring on this BFS algorithm navigation maze python structure?

To basically follow the following algorithm:

function BREADTH-FIRST-SEARCH(problem) returns a solution node or failure
node ← NODE(problem.INITIAL)
if problem.IS-GOAL(node.STATE) then return node
frontier ← a FIFO queue, with node as an element
reached ← {problem.INITIAL}
while not IS-EMPTY(frontier ) do
node ← POP(frontier )
for each child in EXPAND(problem, node) do
s ← child.STATE
if problem.IS-GOAL(s) then return child
if s is not in reached then
add s to reached
add child to frontier
return failure

```
import sys

def parse_map(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        return [[char for char in line] for line in f.read().rstrip("\n").split("\n")][3:]

def count_x(house_map):
    return sum([ row.count('p') for row in house_map ] )

def printable_house_map(house_map):
    return "\n".join(["".join(row) for row in house_map])

def add_x(house_map, row, col):
    return house_map[0:row] + [house_map[row][0:col] + ['p',] + house_map[row][col+1:]] + house_map[row+1:]

def successors(house_map):
    return [ add_x(house_map, r, c) for r in range(0, len(house_map)) for c in range(0,len(house_map[0])) if house_map[r][c] == '.' ]

def is_goal(house_map, k):
    return count_x(house_map) == k 

def bfs_graph_search(house_map):
    fringe = [initial_house_map]
    if house_map.goal_test(node.state):
        return fringe
    fringe = deque([house_map])
    visited = set()
    while fringe:
        fringe = fringe.popleft()
        visited.add(node.state)
        for child in node.expand(problem):
            if child.state not in fringe and child not in visited:
                if house_map.goal_test(child.state):
                    return child
                fringe.append(child)
    return None

def solve(initial_house_map,k):
    fringe = [initial_house_map]
    while len(fringe) > 0:
        for new_house_map in successors( fringe.pop() ):
            if is_goal(new_house_map,k):
                return(new_house_map,True)
            fringe.append(new_house_map)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    house_map=parse_map('map1.txt')
    k = 2 
    print ("Initial ]house map:\n" + printable_house_map(house_map) + "\n\nSearching for solution...\n")
    solution = solve(house_map,k)
    print ("Found:")
    print (printable_house_map(solution[0]) if solution[1] else "False")


class Agent:

    def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):
        self.initial = initial
        self.goal = goal

    def actions(self, state):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def result(self, state, action):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def goal_test(self, state):
        if isinstance(self.goal, list):
            return is_in(state, self.goal)
        else:
            return state == self.goal

    def path_cost(self, c, state1, action, state2):
        return c + 1

    def value(self, state):
        raise NotImplementedError

class FringeGraph:

    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.path_cost = path_cost
        self.depth = 0
        if parent:
            self.depth = parent.depth + 1
    
    def path(self):
        node, path_back = self, []
        while node:
            path_back.append(node)
            node = node.parent
        return list(reversed(path_back))

    def solution(self):
        return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

    def expand(self, agent):
        return [self.child_node(agent, action)
                for action in agent.actions(self.state)]

    def child_node(self, agent, action):
        next_state = agent.result(self.state, action)
        next_node = Node(next_state, self, action, problem.path_cost(self.path_cost, self.state, action, next_state))
        return next_node

class Agent:

    def __init__(self, initial, goal=None):
        self.initial = initial
        self.goal = goal

    def actions(self, state):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def result(self, state, action):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def goal_test(self, state):
        if isinstance(self.goal, list):
            return is_in(state, self.goal)
        else:
            return state == self.goal

    def path_cost(self, c, state1, action, state2):
        return c + 1

    def value(self, state):
        raise NotImplementedError

class FringeGraph:

    def __init__(self, state, parent=None, action=None, path_cost=0):
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.path_cost = path_cost
        self.depth = 0
        if parent:
            self.depth = parent.depth + 1
    
    def path(self):
        node, path_back = self, []
        while node:
            path_back.append(node)
            node = node.parent
        return list(reversed(path_back))

    def solution(self):
        return [node.action for node in self.path()[1:]]

    def expand(self, agent):
        return [self.child_node(agent, action)
                for action in agent.actions(self.state)]

    def child_node(self, agent, action):
        next_state = agent.result(self.state, action)
        next_node = Node(next_state, self, action, agent.path_cost(self.path_cost, self.state, action, next_state))
        return next_node
```

Comment: *"Is anyone open to mentoring on this BFS algorithm...?"* That is off topic for Stack Overflow. You can ask about a *specific* problem you have with your code. If you do, provide the main driver code to run a sample for which the problem occurs, which output was expected, and what you get instead.

Comment: If you want comments and review of a working code consider https://codereview.stackexchange.com/